# How to order a sequential list of jobs

Tags: control-m

We have a large number(few 1000s) of Application Start/Stop jobs that are meant for manual execution. We are attempting to automate Start/Stop during patching cycles. At this time we have created duplicates of all of these jobs into a single Folder to be ordered. The first job must complete before the next can start.

```
Example :
order App1_Stop
then order App2_Stop
then order ...
```

The question is can you order a list of jobs in sequential order in Control-M
without having to duplicate the job definitions them selves?

Answer (score 0):

Control-M connects jobs in a predecessor/successor relationship via conditions that you code/define. Create a script that issues "ctmcreate" with an IN and OUT condition where the OUT condition of job 1 is the IN condition for job 2, etc. The syntax on a Windows machine is something like this:

ctmcreate -tasktype job -jobname StartApp1 -file_path c:\abc -file_name StartApp1.bat -incond start_app1_ok odat and
 -outcond start_app2_ok odat add

As you iterate in your script, use asimple counter to change "StartApp1" to "StartApp2", and the condition names, etc.

There are other, more elegant solutions but that depends on which version of Control-M is being used. Let me know if you wish to discuss further.

Comment: We are using BMC Control-M v8 PL8, I somewhat understand your meaning on this, but a bit more info for the above would be nice. Thank You